# Call method in abstract activity after onCreate of derived activity

Tags: android, abstract-class

I have an abstract Activity that serves as a basis for other activities:
Since I am settings the content view in the derived Activities and I have common UI elements in all activities, I would like to execute code in the derived Activities after the content view has been set.
How can can I do this in the abstract class without putting the method call in every derived Activity?

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void methodToBeCalledAfterOnCreateOfDerivedActivity(){
        //method that does work on common UI elements, so setContentView() needs to have been called
    }
}

public class myActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //how can I call this method automatically at the end of this onCreate without explicitly putting the method here:
        methodToBeCalledAfterOnCreateOfDerivedActivity();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of calls when an Activity is created the first time or the view needs to be recreated is:

```
onCreate()
onCreateView()
onViewCreated()
onViewStateRestored()

onStart()
onResume()
```

So, if you only need your method to be called when the view is created, you could do it in onViewCreated().  If you need it to run whenever your activity is restarted, you would do it in onStart().

Answer (score 0):

`onStart()` is invoked after `onCreate()`. You can probably put your post-`onCreate()` functionality there. Use a flag set in the abstract class `onCreate()` to distinguish between  `onStart()` invocations following `onCreate()` and `onStop()`-`onRestart()`.